# Безопасность веб-приложения

Tags: python, безопасность, flask

Написал, значит, сайт (flask). Для тренировки. Очень простой - на нем будут лишь переводы каких-то английских, интересных мне статей.

База данных содержит лишь информацию о статье, нет никаких комментариев и вообще личных данных кого бы то ни было (возможно, пока).

Какими средствами обеспечивается безопасность такого сайта? Flask защищает от XSS, да, а остальное? Могут ли "хакеры" каким-либо образом навредить сайту или что-то еще подобное? Как защититься? (гуглил, но ничего нормального не нашел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отчего конкретно вы пытаетесь защититься?)
Сами сказали у вас нет никаких данных пользователей, как нет и самих пользователей.

Максимум, что вам на старте нужно, так это настроить создание резервных копий (backup) базы данных, чтобы в случае чего можно было восстановить базу и вернуть сайт к нормальной работе.

PS. многие хостинги сейчас позволяют создавать бекапы автоматически, это часто упрощает задачу.

Comment: вопросов крайне много, начиная от защиты сетевых интерфейсов на VDS-хостинге (аварийное закрытие в случае DDOS, автоматическая intrusion detection c принятием мер) до потенциальных дыр в расширениях flask

Answer (score 2):

**Если у вас будут пользователи**:

- Позаботьтесь о хешировании паролей с солью
- Запрещайте пользователям использовать *короткие* пароли
- Сайт должен иметь сертификат безопасности - LetsEncrypt идеален.

**Безопасность сервера**:

- Подключение к серверу только по ssh с файловым ключем, или через другой сервер по внутреннему IP
- На веб сервере открыты только 80 и 443 порты
- Файлы проекта должны иметь адекватные права доступа, права на запись не root-пользователям по возможности не давайте
- Своевременно устанавливайте обновления безопасности
- Используйте минимум ПО на сервере

**База данных**:

- Убедитесь, что ваше приложение не уязвимо к sql-injection.
- В БД желательно для каждого пользователя иметь не id, а uuid, чтобы их всех нельзя было перебрать и слить тем самым данные
- БД не должна быть доступна для интернета без надежного шифрования канала

**Исходный код**:

- Не храните пароли в исходном коде или git-репозитории. Никогда. Если пароль засветился в git - этот пароль больше использовать нельзя нигде
- Обфусцируйте исходный код проекта перез загрузкой на сервер или скомпилируйте его (через Cython например)

P.S. Ищите больше информации в рекомендациях OWASP